# Jsoup always returns the index of the first appearance of an element

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to parse the following HTML snippet in my project.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Car</td>
            <td class="default"></td>
            <td class="label">Car</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
<table>
```

However, when I used the code below to return the index of the two "car" elements, it always returns 0.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("html.txt"), null);
Elements elements = doc.select("td.label");
for(Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.elementSiblingIndex() + " " + element.text());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this output because for `jsoup` this two `Element` are equals:

```
<td class="label">Car</td>
<td class="label">Car</td>
```

And then it returns the index of the first one he find. Try instead setting Ids to the elements:

```
<td id="car1" class="label">Car</td>
<td class="default"></td>
<td id="car2" class="label">Car</td>
```

And you'll get the desired output:

```
0 Car
2 Car
```

You can also set a different class name, or text value and will also work. For instance:

```
<td class="label">Car</td>
<td class="default"></td>
<td class="label">Bike</td>

0 Car
2 Bike
```

Comment: What if I cannot change the HTML content, is there any way I can do it?

Comment: @rookiedev Simplest way I can think of is selecting all `td`s, iterating over them and reacting only on those with `label` class. Something like http://pastebin.com/asmKxm5B (unless I misunderstood something).

Comment: Yes @Pshemo, that works, but then you miss the power of the selectors

Comment: As I mention, it is only way I could find for now which works. But you are right, if there is some jsoup selector or method which would allow us to avoid `for(i...)` it would be nice to use it.